# How to use one array in different classes?

Tags: ios, arrays

I have an array. It is filled in one class named "SampleDataDAO".

What i need:

In the 2nd class named "MainMenu" i need to keep this code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
daoDS = [[SampleDataDAO alloc] init];
self.ds = daoDS.PopulateDataSource;
}
```

And in the third class named "HView" i need to use array "ds" (NSMutableArray).
But i need to use it already filled from 2nd class, to return the count of elements:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
// Return the number of rows in the section.
return ds.count;
}
```

Thanks for helping!

Comment: You can have that array declared and initialised in AppDelegate. Make that array as a property there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why should not you have a singleton class, and have that array as a member of that singleton class.

More info on singleton found [here](http://www.galloway.me.uk/tutorials/singleton-classes/)

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using singletons, or getting a reference to the array from your appDelegate (which is just the same as using a singleton). A better way would be to pass the array as a reference to the view controller when you create it.

This is similar to the way that you pass a managed object context to view controllers if you are using Core Data, rather than calling down to the app delegate to get it.

Answer (score -1):

Why don't u try to use constant file for this type or requirement.

Use these files for your requirement.

[Constant.h](http://pastebin.com/XePSGaFM)
[Constant.m](http://pastebin.com/sKC42wkC)

Import Constant.h file in your viewController and use that methods to set and get array directly with class name as

```
NSArray *array=[Constant getArray];
```

Or

```
[Constant setArray:array];
```